# Make window.open as anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Currently I am opening a new tab using `window.open(url)` and working fine.

But here, I required to make it as anchor tag because on mouse right click and open link in new tab is not showing for the `window.open`.

Can please suggest how I can convert `window.open` to anchor tag?

Also currently `window.open` capturing the parent window and performing the some activities.

Comment: On the face of it, just do the obvious thing: make it an anchor (perhaps with `target="_blank"`) instead of making it an element where you handle a click and do a `window.open`, and let the browser do its job. Why is this a `window.open` call in the first place? We can't help you more than that without seeing your `window.open` code and knowing why it's code rather than simple markup.

Comment: On window.open, i am passing dynamic url values, if i make it to simple anchor tag, i am not able to capture the parent window/tab on mouse right click and open link in new tab

Comment: You can very well do `oncontextmenu = (evt) => evt.target.href = your_value`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead!

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank"> Link Text </a>
```

Comment: If I use anchor tags, how I can capture parent window/tab details?

Comment: I couldn't get a clear idea about your problem. If I'm correct, you are trying to use JavaScript or other method to generate URLs and open them in a new window.

However, you can use JavaScript to do this.

<--- HTML page --->
`<p id='url'></p>`

<--- JavaScript --->
`var url = "#";
var p_element = document.getElementById('url');
p_element.innerHTML = '<a href=' + url + ' target="_blank">Link Text</a>';`

This will add _<a>_ element to the _<p>_ element with id *'url'*

Comment: currently using window.open capturing the parent window/tab and performing the some activities. My question is how can we capture parent window/tab if use anchor tags instead of window.open